# Get seed and Password of testrpc accounts

Tags: solidity, testrpc

I am working with solidity contracts in development and need to pass seed and password to load wallet. but by running testrpc with --gasLimit, I only get 10 accounts and geslimit. is there any way to get seeds and passwords for that accounts?

Answer (score 1):

When you start testrpc you should see a list of available accounts, private keys and after this section you will see the HD Wallet section with a Mnemonic. Using something like [Metamask](https://metamask.io/) you can 'recover' this wallet using this Mnemonic. You will be asked by MetaMask to enter a password.

Please note that if you have a 'production' wallet accessing the test wallet will close the wallet and you will need to recover from the selected network (so make sure you know your pass phrase!). There are many guides to how to best store and protect your wallet, such as [bitcoin](https://blog.blockchain.com/2015/06/19/recommended-best-practices-when-setting-up-your-blockchain-wallet/):

> Properly store your password, mnemonic, and identifier – Your password
>   (or passphrase) should be written down and placed somewhere safe
>   offline. The same should go for your wallet mnemonic and unique wallet
>   identifier too.

By default you will get one account with a bit of ether (100 from memory). You can then use the private keys to add the other accounts.

Running the command:

```
$testrpc
```

This is what my testrpc output looks like after starting:

```
EthereumJS TestRPC v4.1.3 (ganache-core: 1.1.3)

Available Accounts
==================
(0) 0x22feb83cda1e80fdecdc3c1526a3435a2e5c4d13
(1) 0x24fca3318fee37972375325e5e796ac393209af4
(2) 0x3c357a9e7971a5e54f3baa7b769af3f017d3e6b6
(3) 0x27c8394ddb54ec0c925a9cd2c0fb6632ea22ddc1
(4) 0xb593851880a9bce5ee504bd290a43a56dbddbe3a
(5) 0x01572e23c53d64cc2da4a79b08cdaafd3156b817
(6) 0x3a6aa548627a9dd584491c4ebf4f259b15281845
(7) 0x9e985a53ac2381184379fb539be5987f20c92d41
(8) 0xb576f3e98848342a0cb2dd28ef096c9fcb2fcd86
(9) 0xef937cb51160383b51829e3b0c42a2bab91a4d45

Private Keys
==================
(0) 9e475d31bcc74b95e802baea02a339f99cab59b8da30403d9907bc64d21ffebd
(1) a14dd690b98a2fdfec35761d86b9ee09bdb64c1a84d97779e898f6289d233679
(2) 01c069a0e553d5c95988dc380694ac8a168b9b1dab445c01b0969b4ef4c810ad
(3) 2907831f5c7c45784d063c2e90ed7f523cd800299750da6199f517aa071b8240
(4) fbca6475b1f791f7115e478f59552b26ddc4125cff6d7986821f0793359d0a39
(5) 1e86b8fe9cc1d3bb0017eab8954f615bbef3d6f74f16c55f12101d5efddcae50
(6) 188e6afb5f16ff9567d77fc8d3a7e02bb95a63c5d420ac95f4b7cee9fee80241
(7) aac77ae6b9198ad313fd8d0af9672161ae1cd51a2c2f10f9eb5c9a41b8f80c14
(8) fa04fa50e3d1fd48e64c15b390f3dd97eedc0cdf8046d9a99599474fe64fcc72
(9) a490766376f7fd8fc492d4b3483b8493528fed6d4b2bc2692a6a4f8924009d40

HD Wallet
==================
Mnemonic:      symbol alarm lecture salute deputy all keep ethics neutral embody clinic begin
Base HD Path:  m/44'/60'/0'/0/{account_index}

Listening on localhost:8545
```

Hope this helps.